# Expression for largest eigen value of a real symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have $2\times2$ real symmetric matrix. Is there is any expression for the largest $eigen$ value apart form solving the $eigen$ equation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have the formula $\lambda =\frac{ trace(A) \pm \sqrt{(trace(A))^2 - 4 det(A)}}2.$  what more can you ask for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is. Note that if we write our matrix $A$ in the form $A = Q\Lambda Q^t$, where $Q$ is orthogonal and $\Lambda$ diagonal with entries $\lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2$ , then we have for any $x \in S^1 = \{x \in \mathbf R^2 \mid \def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\abs x = 1\}$ that 
$$ 
\def\<#1>{\left<#1\right>}\<Ax,x> = \<\Lambda Q^t x, Q^tx> = \sum_{i=1}^2 \lambda_i (Q^tx)^2_i \le \lambda_1 \abs{Q^tx}^2  = \lambda_1$$
So 
$$ \lambda_1 \ge \max_{x \in S^1} \<Ax,x> $$
Choosing the eigenvector $v \in S^1$ such that $Av = \lambda_1 v$ shows that 
$$ \lambda_1 = \<Av,v> \le \max_{x\in S^1} \<Ax,x> $$
hence

> $$\lambda_1 = \max_{x\in S^1} \<Ax,x>  = \max_{x \ne 0}\frac{\<Ax,x>}{\<x,x>}$$

Comment: This is absolutely what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.