# Norm inequality about semi-definite matrices

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces, positive-semidefinite

If $A$, $B$ and $A-B$ are positive semi-definite, can we say that $\Vert A \Vert_2 \geq \Vert B \Vert_2$ where $\Vert\cdot\Vert_2$ indicates the spectral norm?

The answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268950/norm-inequality-for-sum-and-difference-of-positive-definite-matrices) has mentioned that

> ... On the other hand, $0\leq X_1\leq X_1+X_2$ implies that
>   $\|X_1\|\leq\|X_1+X_2\|$ ...

but how to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

For a positive semidefinite matrix, 
$$\|A\|_2 = \sup_{\|x\|=1} \langle Ax, x\rangle$$
([reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1311914)). Since $A-B$ is positive semidefinite, 
$$\|A\|_2 = \sup_{\|x\|=1} \langle Bx + (A-B)x, x\rangle
\ge \sup_{\|x\|=1} \langle Bx , x\rangle =\|B\|_2
$$